# tycho build fails with error: Publisher failed. Verify your target-platform-configuration and executionEnvironment are suitable for proper resolution

Tags: eclipse, maven, tycho

I am trying to upgrade by application from tycho 1.x and java 8 to tycho 2.7.5 and java 11. Everything works fine in eclipse but when I try to build the project in maven it fails and gives the following error: "Publisher failed. Verify your target-platform-configuration and executionEnvironment are suitable for proper resolution". However, my executionEnvironment is set to JavaSE-11. The repository I am using is "https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-06". When I ran the maven build in debug mode I found the below stack trace.

[image]

Below is the link of the java source file where it fails in line 105.
https://git.eclipse.org/c/equinox/rt.equinox.p2.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.eclipse/src/org/eclipse/equinox/p2/publisher/eclipse/ProductAction.java

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: ProductAction is processing your .product file which seems to be incorrect - so show us that. Also note that the current version of tycho is 3.0.3

Comment: I didn't upgrade the java version in <vm> section of .product which resulted in the issue. Managed to fix it with your hint. Thanks! 

I tried to build maven with tycho 3.03 + java 11 but it didn't work, this is the reason I moved to tycho 2.7.5. I will give it a try again.

Comment: _"I didn't upgrade the java version in <vm> section of .product"_ - Nowadays a Java VM can be easily added to your product by including a [Eclipse JustJ](https://www.eclipse.org/justj/) JRE as a feature into your product (with that, also the Java VM used to run your Eclipse RCP can be upgraded by p2).